# Add jQuery / JavaScript code to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a website that when the user leaves any of the text fields blank, the border of the box will turn red. I figured it out in css with these lines of code

```
.input-box{
  border-color: red;
}

.input-box:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

But I want to implement this in my php code if the fields are empty. I've been searching this all around an cannot find a solution. I even tried JavaScript and got to this point

```
if(empty($fullname)){
  echo "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      document.getElementByClassName('input-box').style.borderStyle = 'solid';,
      document.getElementByClassName('input-box').style.border = '';,
      document.getElementByClassName('input-box').style.borderColor = 'red';
    </script>
  ";
}

if(empty($email)){
  echo "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      document.getElementByClassName('input-box').style.borderStyle = 'solid';,
      document.getElementByClassName('input-box').style.border = '';,
      document.getElementByClassName('input-box').style.borderColor = 'red';
    </script>
  ";
}

if(empty($password)){
  echo "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      document.getElementByClassName('input-box').style.borderStyle = 'solid';,
      document.getElementByClassName('input-box').style.border = '';,
      document.getElementByClassName('input-box').style.borderColor = 'red';
    </script>
  ";
}

if(!empty($fullname) && !empty($email) && !empty($password)){
  echo "you're in";
}
```

But it is not working. So all I want to do is when the user leaves a field empty, the border of the box will turn red and the outline will be none.

Comment: No thank you! Thanks for your comment

Comment: I think you want to add the css class to your text box when it's empty. Like: `if(empty($fullname)){ echo '<script>document.getElementById("{id 
 of fullname input box}").classList.add("input-box");</script>'; }` Or check out using jQuery addClass https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ *Also, why not change `.input-box` to something more descriptive like: `.input-box-err`

Comment: So pretty much when empty, I can make a css code and combine them and the code will run pretty much css in php lines?

Comment: The above code will make border red for all textboxes which has input-box class.

Comment: I think you should use document.getElementsByName() method for particular textbox name.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so you cannot assign properties like style.

Here's the JavaScript you want:

```
var inputs= document.getElementsByClassName("input-box");
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  inputs[i].style.border = '';
  inputs[i].style.borderColor = 'red';
}
```

Comment: Sorry...some typos

Comment: I put that and still the same D:

Comment: document.getElementsByName('name')[0].style.borderColor="red";

Answer (score 0):

My Code is based on jQuery.

Hope It will help you...

```js
 $('#user-form').submit(function(e) {
  var name  = $('#name').val();
  var email  = $('#email').val();
  var phone  = $('#phone').val();
  var address  = $('#address').val();
  var dob   = $('#dob').val();
  if(name=="")  $('#name').addClass('input-box'); else $('#name').removeClass('input-box');
  if(email=="")  $('#email').addClass('input-box'); else $('#email').removeClass('input-box');
  if(phone=="")  $('#phone').addClass('input-box'); else $('#phone').removeClass('input-box');
  if(address=="")  $('#address').addClass('input-box');else $('#address').removeClass('input-box');
  if(dob=="")   $('#dob').addClass('input-box'); else $('#dob').removeClass('input-box');
  if((name=="")||(email=="")||(phone=="")||(address=="")||(dob==""))event.preventDefault();
  
 });
```

```css
.input-box{
  border-color: red;
}

.input-box:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="user-form" action="q.php">
 <p><label>Name : </label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></p>
 <p><label>Email : </label><input  type="text" id="email" name="email" /></p>
 <p><label>Phone : </label><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" /></p>
 <p><label>Address : </label><input type="text" id="address" name="address" /></p>
 <p><label>DOB : </label><input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" /></p>
 <p><button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

While I am not a big fun of mixing PHP/server code with front end like that, there is an obvious error (unless it was intended). Since you are using class input-box for all, if any one field is empty, all will be marked as empty.

Anyway, try the following:

first, the styles you want to apply for empty fields are the same. So, in your css file define one. E.g.

```
 .needed-field {border:1px solid red;}
```

Then give each field a unique id while keeping the class input-box in place.

Then do two things in your PHP file: remove any possible bad field from before when submitting the form or something:

```
     $('.input-box').removeClass('needed-field');
```

Then for each one:

```
     if(empty($fullname)){
    echo "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
           $('#fullname').addClass('needed-field');

       </script>
      ";
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Edit:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">


     <style>

        .needed_field {border:5px solid red;}

        </style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
                 <form action="so/1.php" method="post">
                 <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" class="input-box"><br/>
                 <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="input-box"><br/>
                 <input type="text" id="password" name="password" class="input-box"><br/>

                 <input type="submit" value="Sumbit" id="submit" name="submit">

                 </form>
                 <script>
                 $('.input-box').removeClass('needed_field');
                 <?php
                if($_POST['submit']){
                    //echo '<script>'

                    //echo '</script>';

                    $fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
                    $email=$_POST['email'];
                    $pwd=$_POST['pwd'];

                    if(empty($fullname)){
                        echo "$('#fullname').addClass('needed_field');";
                    }


                }
                ?>

                </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added it and didn't get the results D:

Comment: Copy + paste the code in your .php file. See the updates. Of course, form action should be adjusted...